# ColdFusion pages displayed as Raw Code

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, coldfusion, cfml

I have a Tomcat 6 server running multiple application, in one of these applications the JSPs refer to links in a ColdFusion project.  In production we have Apache setup to change the DocumentRoot to the ColdFusion webroot, however as we are only running Tomcat I can't do this (i.e. our system does not have a httpd.conf or apache2.conf file).  I tried setting up a docBase in a context file to point to the ColdFusion project webroot but that didn't work so instead I set up symbolic links inside the tomcat webroot.  This linked to the pages correctly but instead of parsing the page it displays the ColdFusion code.

I don't have any experience with ColdFusion except changing the settings to point to the database I want through the Admin interface.

Tomcat webroot:

```
webapps/ (tomcat webroot)
    cfProject/www/ (ColdFusion webroot)
    otherProject/pages/*.jsp
```

Can anyone help me?  If you need more information I will update the question as we go.

UPDATE: ColdFusion version: 9

UPDATE: Context for application setup and symlinks removed however ColdFusion source is still being output and displayed on the page rather than the code being run and displaying the results.

UPDATE: I've installed apache2 and linked it up to tomcat, it is now connecting to ColdFusion correctly and loading all the .cf files from the JSP pages, however the ColdFusion pages are still being displayed in plain text.  Seems the coldFusion pages that are being redirected via a ProxyPass are working but the ones from the DocumentRoot location are not.  Will update if I figure it out.

UPDATE: Got it working in the end, I had to be careful with the order of the ProxyPass rules so once I sorted that out and gave tomcat and apache a restart the pages started coming through correctly.  Thanks for all your input Peter.

Thanks in advance,
Alexei Blue.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion is this? How was it installed?

Comment: The ColdFusion project is built into a WAR and dropped into the web apps folder manually.  I'm not sure of the version number but it's not running as a standalone server, it's just running from tomcat.  The pages load fine if I put the full web address to the project and page I want so I'm not sure why using a symlink is not parsing the page correctly.

Comment: _"The pages load fine if I put the full web address to the project and page I want so I'm not sure why using a symlink is not parsing the page correctly."_ - huh? What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to setup URL rewriting?

Comment: (depending on how it's been setup, you might be able to determine version by forcing an error - e.g. visiting a non-existent page, or trying to access Application.cfc)

Comment: CF scripts and pages are accessed through the JSP's relative to the CF webroot e.g. href"/index.cfm" in a JSP.  In production we set DocumentRoot in apache to point to the CF webroot.  I have managed to setup a context and removed the symlinks but I'm still getting CF's raw code. In the page source the browser was sent a <cfquery> tag (from a CF file that runs an SQL query) and on the page the SQL is display instead of the results.  It looks like the pages are linking i.e. being found which they weren't being before but not being run, any ideas how I can get them to run? FYI running CF9.

Comment: I understand what displaying the raw code means. I don't understand what you're doing with symlinks. Your comment makes it sound like you're doing some sort of proxying in JSP, but it's equally possible you're just using convoluted terms to say you have JSP files generating HTML with simple hyperlinks. :/
Can you post the `web.xml` contained in the WAR file? (Does it have a servlet entry for CF and appropriate servlet mappings?)

Comment: Also, what is the reason for not using the same Apache-based setup you have in production?

Comment: In production cold fusion is run in a separate tomcat instance so to keep the links in the JSP's tidy a ProxyPass was added so yes it's a proxy.  We didn't setup Apache in our system because we didn't think we would need it, it was only when trying to include the CF pages we came across this issue.  The web.xml in my other project is quite large however it does not have servlet for CF, will it need one?

Comment: Looking at this page: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-786c.html#WSA0035455-0E0B-4866-8F04-E44A66B33A90 and some of the CF pages in the CF project I can see there is no tag to say which Application.cfc should be used, does ColdFusion determine this automatically or should I set this up?

Comment: If Tomcat has not been told to hand *.cfm requests to ColdFusion, it wont do so - and they will get picked up by the default file servlet, which will display them as plain text (i.e. the raw files).

Comment: The CF project has lots of servlets setup for mapping CF file types including *.cfm but it says "Some servers don't support wildcards (Tomcat, SunONE)"  Could this be an issue?

Comment: Maybe I need to set the docbase in tomcat the same for all applications, I wonder if ColdFusion is looking in the tomcat webroot instead of it's own webroot, will test and let you know.

Comment: All JEE servers support wildcards, but the JEE standard only requires a _single_ wildcard (`*.cfm`) but not _multiple_ wildcards (`*.cfm/*`) - you can do the former with Tomcat but not the latter.

Comment: _"We didn't setup Apache in our system because we didn't think we would need it"_ - your production system is working. This one isn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I installed Apache2 and set up proxy ajp to connect to my Tomcat application listening on port 80.  Tomcat has a connector to do this automatically so I had no issues there.  Then, in the default virtual host in sites-enabled, I changed the DocumentRoot to point to the base of my ColdFusion project.  (Not sure if this is needed but it doesn't hurt).  Then, also inside the default virtual host, I added ProxyPass rules to connect different URL's to ColdFusion.  The bit that stumped me for some time was adding a rule that pointed to the root URL:

```
ProxyPass / /ColdFusion/www
```

Because the ProxyPass rules are all processed it was messing up the URL causing pages not found etc.  Once I fixed this and restarted I was sorted.

Thanks again Peter for your help on this.